# Can this question be solved in any way other than using l'hopital's rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{x+2}{(x-30)^{1/5} - (x^2 + 12)^{1/4} + 4}$$

Comment: Since a power of a non-integer power of a negative number is involved, you have to choose a certain branch of logarithm.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain could you please elaborate a bit? what do you mean by "a power of a non-integer power of a negative number is involved"?

Comment: @NOT: what would you say the first term of the denominator evaluates to in the limit?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Since $x^2+12>0$ there's no need for choosing a branch of $a^{1/4}$. And since near $-2$ $x-30<0,$ and the power is $1/5,$ the simple approach is to use the negatiove of the fifth power of $30-x$ [again no need for a branch if interpreted this way.]

Comment: I guess that just answering "Yes" is not acceptable, although it is correct. There are (at least) two different answers, both agreeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly can be.

Write $f(x) = (x - 30)^{1/5} - (x^2 + 12)^{1/4}$. Note that $f(-2) = -4$.

Note that $\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{(x - 30)^{1/5} - (x^2 + 12)^{1/4} + 4}{x + 2} = \lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{f(x) - f(-2)}{x - -2}$ is, by definition, $f'(-2)$.

Therefore, the above limit is equal to $f'(-2)$. Now $f'(x) = \frac{1}{5} (x - 30)^{-4/5} - 2x\frac{1}{4}(x^2 + 12)^{-3/4}$, so we see that $f'(-2) = \frac{1}{80} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{11}{80}$.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{x + 2}{(x - 30)^{1/5} - (x^2 + 12)^{1/4} + 4} = \frac{1}{\lim\limits_{x \to -2} \frac{(x - 30)^{1/5} - (x^2 + 12)^{1/4} + 4}{x + 2}} = \frac{1}{\frac{11}{80}} = \frac{80}{11}$.

Comment: Nice that we agree.

Comment: Hi @Mark Saving. Just a keen observer here. Could you tell me where you got the definition: $f(-2) = -4$ from?

Comment: @EB3112 I just plugged in $-2$ into the definition of $f$. We have $f(-2) = (-2 - 30)^{1/5} - ((-2)^2 + 12)^{1/4} = (-32)^{1/5} - 16^{1/4} = -2 - 2 = -4$.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that

Comment: @martycohen I would have been rather concerned if we didn't agree. The generalised binomial theorem was my second thought, but it seemed to rely on some fairly advanced results to solve a problem likely encountered at the beginning of a calculus course.

Comment: Well, using l'Hospital is (more or less) the same as the above computation...

Comment: @Mark Saving: It's easy to make computational errors, so it's comforting when two different ways get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Let us write $x=-2+h$.
We use the formulas:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A^5-B^5&=(A-B)(A^4+A^3B+A^2B^2 +AB^3+B^4)\ ,\\
A^4-B^4&=(A-B)(A^3+A^2B+AB^2+B^3)
\end{aligned}
$$
below. We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{2+(x-30)^{1/5}}{x+2}  
&= 
\frac{32^{1/5}-(32-h)^{1/5}}h
\\
&= 
\frac{32^{1/5}-(32-h)^{1/5}}{32-(32-h)}
\\
&=\frac1{32^{4/5}+32^{3/5}(32-h)^{1/5}+\dots+(32-h)^{1/5}}
\\
&\to\frac 1{5\cdot 16}=\frac 1{80}\qquad\text{ for }h\to0\ ,
\\[3mm]
\frac{2-(x^2+12)^{1/4}}{x+2}  
&= 
\frac{16^{1/4}-(h^2-4h+16)^{1/4}}h
\\
&= 
\frac
{16^{1/4}-(h^2-4h+16)^{1/4}}
{16-(h^2-4h+16)}
\cdot
\frac{16-(h^2-4h+16)}
h
\\
&=
\frac 1{16^{3/4} +\dots+(h^2+4h+16)^{3/4}}\cdot (4-h)
\\
&\to \frac 1{4\cdot 8}\cdot 4=\frac 18 \qquad\text{ for }h\to0\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so the sum of the two expressions
$$
\frac{2+(x-30)^{1/5}}{x+2}  
+
\frac{2-(x^2+12)^{1/4}}{x+2}  
$$
converges to the sum
$$
\frac1{80}+\frac 18=\frac{1+10}{80}=\frac {11}{80}\ .
$$
It remains to take the reversed fraction...

Answer (score 2):

Want
$\lim\limits_{x \to -2} f(x)
$
where
$f(x)
=\frac{x+2}{(x-30)^{1/5} - (x^2 + 12)^{1/4} + 4}
$.

Let
$x = y-2$.

We just need the
generalized binomial theorem.

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=f(y-2)\\
&=\frac{x+2}{(x-30)^{1/5} - (x^2 + 12)^{1/4} + 4}\\
&=\frac{y}{(y-32)^{1/5} - ((y-2)^2 + 12)^{1/4} + 4}\\
&=\frac{y}{(y-32)^{1/5} - (y^2-4y+16)^{1/4} + 4}\\
&=\frac{y}{(-2)(1-(y/32))^{1/5} - 2(1-(y/4)+(y^2/16))^{1/4} + 4}\\
&=\frac{y}{(-2)(1-(y/(160))+O(y^2)) - 2(1-(y/16)+O(y^2)) + 4}\\
&=\frac{y}{(-2)+(y/(80))+O(y^2) - 2+(y/8)+O(y^2) + 4}\\
&=\frac{y}{y/(80)+(y/8)+O(y^2)}\\
&=\frac{y}{11y/(80)+O(y^2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{11/(80)+O(y)}\\
&=\dfrac{80}{11}+O(y)\\
&\to\dfrac{80}{11}
\qquad\text{as }y \to 0\\\\
\end{array}
$